# toNumber is not a function while writing tests

Tags: solidity, truffle-test

I am trying to write a simple test to validate a condition, however it fails saying 'toNumber is not a function'

Here is the test condition

```
const quorum = await wallet.quorum;
assert(quorum.toNumber() === 2);
```

quorum is a public uint256 variable defined in the contract

```
uint256 public quorum;
```

Any idea, what could be missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. it was a silly mistake.
Missed the round brackets when calling the public variable.

```
  const quorum = await wallet.quorum();
```

Comment: take care the uint can be very very big and JavaScript cannot handle it. Better to use big numbers libraries

Comment: do you mean something like BN.toNumber() ???

Comment: no "quorum" is uint256 therefore it is already a bignumber. my point take care when convert BigNumber to Number is not safe :) if you are using etherjs 5 then "This will throw an error if the value is greater than or equal to Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER or less than or equal to Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER." https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/#BigNumber--BigNumber--methods--conversion

Comment: how to convert big numbers in case of web3.js

Comment: Is this a correct way of doing using web3js --- 
web3.utils.toBN(quorum).toNumber()

Comment: you should not convert bignumber to number unless it is safe. otherwise you could loss data.  idk what is the best way to do that but keep in mind it is not safe